# Fiddler with Docker Container on WSL2

Tags: docker-compose, fiddler, wsl-2

Connecting from Windows to a Docker (compose) containers running in WLS2 works including debugging. However, Fiddler is not able to monitor the Docker http(s) traffic. I've found a few hints/partials on how this could work, but no success yet. Does anyone have more complete advice/pointers?

Comment: Fiddler uses the Windows proxy settings to redirect traffic through it. WSL does not respect this proxy setting so you have to manually configure proxy inside WSL: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1570

Comment: Even following the info in that issue I couldn't get it working.